# Meteor tap-i18n: How to localise account package (js)?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I have setup tap-i18n to localize my meteor app. I am able to localise html template pages. But when I am trying to localize account package string it is not working.

This is what I am trying -

```
AccountsTemplates.configure({
  defaultLayout: 'emptyLayout',
  confirmPassword: false,
  showLabels: false,
  showPlaceholders: true,
  negativeValidation: true,
  positiveValidation: true,
  negativeFeedback: true,
  positiveFeedback: false,
  onSubmitHook: onFormSubmission,
  preSignUpHook: preSignup,
  sendVerificationEmail: true,
  enforceEmailVerification: true,
  texts: {
    'navSignIn': 'Sign in',
    'signUpLink_pre': TAPi18n.__('not_member'),
    'signUpLink_link': 'Register now',
    title: {
      'signUp': 'Register with Us'
    }
  }
});
```

You can see `'signUpLink_pre': TAPi18n.__('not_member')`. But in UI I see `'not_member'`

Here is the locale file - 
`{ "not_member":"Not a member yet?" }`

Comment: For account package i18n is achieved using accounts-t9n package.
https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#i18n